# How do I go about creating a javascript ipad app that uses local storage?

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad

I need to create an internal admin app. The app needs to be able to:

**For V1**
- Wrap and execute javascript code
- Will not rely on any iOS code other than perhaps the code necessary to   load the javascript.
- Uses local storage

**For V2**
- Work offline (which means javascript code needs to be loaded in)

Any ideas on how to go about implementing such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the easiest and best supported way is to use [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/). They did all the work of wrapping a Webview in a native app and have a rich set of plugins for integration with all kinds of mobile APIs.

Since the app will be running in an embedded browser [you can simply access the normal Localstorage APIs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html).

[The Cordova tutorial](https://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/) by [@ccoenraets](https://twitter.com/ccoenraets) may be a good way to get started.

Answer (score 0):

From my findings the following two are great solutions:

1. [Ionic](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic)
2. [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/)